# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-5, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Hi I'm getting this error

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.Contacts_ContactID".
>
> The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-COGMakati-20140119015553", table "dbo.Contacts", column 'ContactID'.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

I'm using Entity Framework and MVC 5's IdentityUser so I'm really lost on what I'm doing :|

This is what I'm trying to populate:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Birthday { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Referred By")]
    public string LifegroupPreference { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Civil Status")]
    public string CivilStatus { get; set; }

    public int EducationID { get; set; }
    public int WorkID { get; set; }
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public int FamilyID { get; set; }
    public int SpiritualID { get; set; }
    public int GrowthMilestoneID { get; set; }
        
    [ForeignKey("EducationID")]
    public virtual Education Education { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("WorkID")]
    public virtual Work Work { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ContactID")]
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FamilyID")]
    public virtual Family Family { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SpiritualID")]
    public virtual Spiritual Spiritual { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GrowthMilestoneID")]
    public virtual GrowthMilestone GrowthMilestone { get; set; }
}
```

The way I see it, the `Contact` is being created before the User is even made. I don't know why this happens, since when not using `IdentityUser` this code populates it just fine.

Now this is the `Register` method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = model.GetUser();
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var idManager = new IdentityManager();
            idManager.AddUserToRole(user.Id, "User");

            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return RedirectToAction("ViewAllMembers", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Is this happening only for Contact ? What about the rest of the Foreign objects ?

Comment: Hi @Rakhita! I'm not really sure how to test this. But assuming that the code is read from top to bottom, then I'm guessing that it has passed through Education and Work before having an error with Contact. Thank you!

Comment: If you already have a database and made changes in the Model later and try to run you get this error. Change the database name and try. You will be fine. If acceptable delete your database  and start again

Comment: Hi @Reddy, what I did was delete the .mdf file located in my App_Data folder and my entire migrations folder. I re-enabled migrations, added a new migration, and updated the database. Same problem =/ Or is there a better way of deleting a database?

Comment: Has your dataBase got lot of information in it??  Would you mind deleting Db .. are you using SQL server?

Comment: Not much, I can still delete it if I have to. I'm not using SQL Server. How do I delete the db? Is it different from what I have stated above? (Deleting the .mdf files located in my App_Data folder of the project)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are probably trying to access or insert using a non-existent foreign key. Go to your `dbo.Contacts` Table and look for the record with that key. You'll find no record with that key in the table. You need to create a record with that key or use another (existing) key.

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating the FK obect as well than you should first store it and retrieve its ID, failing todo so will cause the FK_Key to fail as you have no FK value.

Walter

Comment: Thank you! I resolved this by removing the id's responsible for the navigation properties and instead put navigation properties for each table to user.

Answer (score 2):

If you want you can allow to reference to non-existent records

```
Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.Users NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Users_dbo.Roles_RoleID]");
```