# insert multiple row in a single form using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

here my question is that where user enters area details like place-name, noofplaces, like that after creating user details here user entered noofplaces, so how many enters(10,20 or even 100) that many rows should be created.

here is the code worked for me

**Area Model**

```
`public class Area
{
    [Key]
    public int AreaID { get; set; }

    public string ParkingPlaceName { get; set; }
    public int NoOfParkingPlaces { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal MinimumCharges { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Precision(25,22)]
    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
    [Precision(25,22)]
    public decimal Longitude { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ParkingPlace> ParkingPlaces { get; set; }
}
```

}`

**ParkingPlace Model**

```
public class ParkingPlace
{
    [Key]
    public int ParkID { get; set; }
    public string PlaceId { get; set; }
    public int AreaID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public virtual Area Areas { get; set; }
}
```

**controller code**

```
    public ActionResult Create(string areaName)
    {
        Area area = db.Areas.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ParkingPlaceName == areaName);
        return View(area);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ParkID,PlaceId,AreaID")] List<Place> place)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach(var i in place)
            {
                db.Places.Add(i);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Area");
        }
        return View(place);
    }
```

**View Code**

```
@model CarParking.Models.Area

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","ParkingPlace", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    <hr />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Place ID's</th>
            <th>Area ID's</th>
        </tr>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.NoOfParkingPlaces; i++)
        {
            <tr class="form-group">
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBox("[" + i + "].PlaceId", "P.Id_" + i + "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessage("[" + i + "].PlaceId", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBox("[" + i + "].AreaID", Model.AreaID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessage("[" + i + "].AreaID", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Hidden("[" + i + "].PlaceId_Status", false)
                    @Html.ValidationMessage("[" + i +"].PlaceId_Status", "", new { @class = "text-danger"})
                </td>

            </tr>

        }
    </table>
    <p>
       <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </p>

 }
```

Comment: What happen if you provide different Area IDs in UI instead of same Id? Also check [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518995/the-insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint-error)

Comment: thanks for response

Comment: according to code `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.NoOfParkingPlaces ; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.TextBox("[" + i + "].PlaceId", "P.Id_" + i + "")</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBox("["+ i +"].AreaID", Model.AreaID)</td>
            </tr>
        }` here Model.NoOfParkingPlaces assume value is 3 so in html view in browser it will shows 6 textboxes. 3 for placeId and 3 for AreaId so Areaid is fixed value and PlaceId is different so i want to save all of them